# Composable invocations can only happen from the context of an @Composable function....but it is in that context

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to invoke a simple dialog in KMP Compose. The call to the Dialog is within a Composable function, so I do not understand the error.

The code looks like this. The line where the error occurs is marked with a comment.

```
class WithdrawScreen: Screen {
@Composable
override fun Content() {
    val navigator = LocalNavigator.currentOrThrow
    val openDialog = remember { mutableStateOf(false)  }
    val realm = openPelletRealm()
    val pelletLots: RealmResults<PelletLot> = retrieveAllPellotLots(realm)


    MaterialTheme {

        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {
            Text("Withdraw Screen")

            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(bottom = 20.dp),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly
            ) {
                Text("Lot #")
                Text("# of Pellets")
                Text("Lot Date")
                Text("Size")
                Text("Pellets Needed")
            }

            val textFields = remember { Array(pelletLots.size) { mutableStateOf("") } }

            for ((index, item) in pelletLots.withIndex()) {
                Row(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .padding(bottom = 5.dp),
                    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly
                ) {
                    Text(item.lotNumber)
                    Text(item.numberOfPelletsInLot.toString())
                    Text(convertLongDateToString(item.dateOfLot))
                    Text(item.pelletSize.toString())
                    TextField(
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 5.dp).width(width = 50.dp),
                        value = textFields[index].value,  //textFields[index],
                        onValueChange = { textFields[index].value = it })
                }
            }

            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))

            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(bottom = 20.dp),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly
            ) {
                Button(onClick = {
                    closePelletRealm(realm)
                    navigator.pop()
                }) {
                    Text("Back")
                }
                Button(onClick = {
                    for ((index, item) in textFields.withIndex()) {

                        if (pelletLots[index].numberOfPelletsInLot < textFields[index].value.toInt()) {

                        }
                        else
                        {

                            AlertDialog(  //<------ ERROR IS HERE
                                onDismissRequest = {
                                    openDialog.value = false
                                },
                                title = {
                                    Text(text = "Dialog Title Will Show Here")
                                },
                                text = {
                                    Text("Here is a description text of the dialog")
                                },
                                confirmButton = {
                                    Button(

                                        onClick = {
                                            openDialog.value = false
                                        }) {
                                        Text("Confirm Button")
                                    }
                                },
                                dismissButton = {
                                    Button(

                                        onClick = {
                                            openDialog.value = false
                                        }) {
                                        Text("Dismiss Button")
                                    }
                                }
                            )
                        }

                     }

                    closePelletRealm(realm)
                    navigator.pop()
                }) {
                    Text("Submit")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What is it that I'm doing wrong? The call to create the dialog is within an @Composable so, to me, the error seems very misleading.

Comment: "*The call to create the dialog is within an @Composable*" -- No, the call is within the `onClick` lambda. This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66952179/not-able-to-show-alertdialog-from-onclick-in-jetpack-compose

Answer (score 2):

Your making a mistake
You can't call a composable function from a click event

Rather make a state

```
val showDialog = mutableStateOf(false)
```

Then when show dialog is true, call the AlertDialogComposable

```
if(showDialog.value) //call your alert Dialog here
```

This should be done on a composable not a click event